# Completely white areas show reddish lines on the laptop screen

Tags: laptop, lcd, visual-artifacts

Video showing the issue :

https://youtu.be/8Sd-mw77Evg

Summary : the areas where the color is uniform, for example full white, show vertical lines.

I seem to recall that GPU does not update all the time the pixels which don't change but the LCD keeps in memory the unchanged pixels in order to reduce necessary data transfer.

So it sounds like the issue could be that the flash of the LCD PCB which should hold pixel value is corrupted or something like this.

- Is that a common issue?
- Can someone confirm if my theory is correct?
- What could be the cause, the LCD or the GPU?

Comment: See what happens if you have a black background  with a white line and white rectangle in paint.

Comment: First test - take a screenshot & view it on another device. If it looks normal, then you have a hardware issue.